# Component is not updating (react-redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm another guy with the same question; Sorry, but I could not see yet my error.I'm suspecting is something about mutation, but I tried (almost) everything, getting mad. My component is not updating when I add stuff to my store, it seems is rendering just for once (first time)

I was trying with lifecycles but nothing

```
ACTION


export default async function getJoke() {
    let jk = await axios.get('https://jokeapi.p.rapidapi.com/category/any' ,{ headers :{
        'x-rapidapi-host' :  'jokeapi.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key'  : "***********************" }} );

    let joke;
    if(jk.data.type === 'single') {
        joke = jk.data.joke 
    }  else {
        joke = { setup : jk.data.setup,
                 delivery : jk.data.delivery}
    }

   let getjoke = {
       type : 'GETJOKE',
       joke
   } 
   store.dispatch(getjoke) ;   
}


REDUCER

let initialState = { jokes : [ ] };

function joke (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GETJOKE' : return {...state,
             jokes :[...state.jokes, {jokes: action.joke}]
             } ;
        default : return state;
    }
}
export default joke;

REDUCER-INDEX

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import joke from './joke'

export default combineReducers ({
    joke 

})

STORE 

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import Combined from './reducer';
export default createStore(Combined);


COMPONENT

import React from 'react';
import BotJoke from './btnJoke';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store'

 class joke extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             jokes : props.jokes
         }
         console.log('MENDA',this.state.jokes);

     }
     componentDidMount() {
         console.log('willdisssd receive props');
/*          this.setState({jokes : [...this.state.jokes, nextProps]})
 */
     }

     componentWillMount(){
         console.log('will mount',this.state.jokes);
         console.log('Entra');
         console.log('NEXT PROPS');


     }

   render() {
   return (
       <div>
           <BotJoke/>
           { this.state.jokes !== undefined  ? <h1>Hay bromas</h1>: <h1>NO HAY BROMAS</h1> } 
       </div>
   )
 } }


function mapStateToProps (state) {
    console.log('STorE', store.getState());
    return {
        jokes : state.jokes
    }

}

let connection = connect(mapStateToProps)(joke);
export default connection;
```

Comment: I guess you need to do `jokes: state.joke.jokes`. You are missing reducer hierarchy here which you have added in combineReducers. FYI, you don't need to combine if you have only 1 reducer

Comment: You were right!!! thank you very much; I'd appreciate you explains a little bit more or give some reference about hierarchy cause i'm not getting it very well.

Comment: Well you can ready more about `combineReducers` here https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers. At a high level, when you use a reducer directly with store then you can directly access them from redux state but combineReducer will create child hierarchy in parent object and put all the results inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is an anti pattern, using the props to setState though you can just use props directly instead.

Use `this.props.jokes` everywhere in your component, it should work. Let me know.

**EDIT:**

Assuming you want the jokes to be an array:

```
REDUCER

let initialState = { jokes : [ ] };

function joke (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GETJOKE' : return {...state,
             jokes :[...state.jokes, action.joke]
             } ;
        default : return state;
    }
}
export default joke;

REDUCER-INDEX

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import joke from './joke'

export default combineReducers ({
    joke 

})

STORE 

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import Combined from './reducer';
export default createStore(Combined);


COMPONENT

import React from 'react';
import BotJoke from './btnJoke';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store'

 const joke = (props) => {

   const length = props.jokes.length

   return (
       <div>
           <BotJoke/>
           { length !== 0  ? <h1>{JSON.stringify(props.jokes[length-1])}</h1>: <h1>NO HAY BROMAS</h1> } 
       </div>
   )
 }



function mapStateToProps (state) {
    console.log('STorE', store.getState());
    return {
        jokes : state.jokes
    }

}

let connection = connect(mapStateToProps)(joke);
export default connection;
```

Comment: Yes, I was using at first a function as a component, with props.jokes , but I got the same , does not update...

Comment: Should jokes be an array? or an object?

Comment: Check out the updated solution. Let me know if that works and if you need more help, add the code to codesandbox and share the link. Or else it's hard to help you any further.

Comment: I tried your code and I got an error in compilation cause props.joke is undefined at first attemp. So I modified yours a little bit adding an if sentence and thats took me back to beginning :( My store look like this {joke:{jokes:[{..},{..},{..}]}} ; you can see the entire code in https://github.com/DavidAbellan/react-redux-jokes ; Thank you

Comment: Is working already , the problem was on mapStatetoProps => state.joke.jokes .It was a hierarchy problem. many thanks